# react-native "Export statement may only appear at top level" was working fine until cleaning project how do I find out the issue?

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, metro-bundler

I'm only seeing mention of changes in babelrc etc. online for this message.  I've tried to remove the dependency that gives me this error and it appears that then next dependency evaluated returns the same message.

The error is coming from any/all of my node_modules folder and the code is correct.  I'm guessing something has changed w/ versions of something in my dev dependencies but not sure how to track it down...

I'm using RN 61.5 old I know but this is a production env and can't update atm.  Any help on where to look to find the issue please?

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@nartc/react-native-barcode-mask": "1.1.5",
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.7.1",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.2",
        "@react-native-community/picker": "1.6.5",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.2.3",
        "clone": "2.1.2",
        "expo-keep-awake": "8.0.0",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "8.0.0",
        "lodash": "4.17.19",
        "moment": "2.24.0",
        "react": "16.9.0",
        "react-native": "0.61.5",
        "react-native-ble-manager": "git+https:/react-native-ble-manager.git#mergeUpstreamv750",
        "react-native-camera": "3.15.1",
        "react-native-date-picker": "2.7.12",
        "react-native-device-battery": "2.0.0",
        "react-native-device-info": "5.5.1",
        "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
        "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.10",
        "react-native-fs": "2.16.4",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.5.3",
        "react-native-json-tree": "^1.3.0",
        "react-native-lock-task": "1.0.8",
        "react-native-masked-text": "1.13.0",
        "react-native-modal": "11.5.4",
        "react-native-reanimated": "1.4.0",
        "react-native-restart": "0.0.17",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.2",
        "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.23",
        "react-native-svg": "12.0.3",
        "react-native-unimodules": "0.7.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
        "react-native-version-number": "0.3.6",
        "react-navigation": "4.1.1",
        "react-navigation-animated-switch": "0.5.5",
        "react-navigation-header-buttons": "3.0.5",
        "react-navigation-hooks": "1.1.0",
        "react-navigation-stack": "2.0.13",
        "react-redux": "7.1.3",
        "redux": "4.0.5",
        "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
        "redux-storage": "4.1.2",
        "redux-storage-engine-reactnativeasyncstorage": "1.0.7",
        "reselect": "4.0.0",
        "sedcommon": "git+https://sedcommon.git#p2.3.6",
        "semver": "7.3.2",
        "socket.io-client": "4.1.3",
        "styled-components": "5.0.0",
        "ts-optchain": "0.1.8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.7",
        "@carimus/metro-symlinked-deps": "^1.1.0",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.6",
        "@types/jest": "~26.0.13",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.153",
        "@types/node": "^14.0.6",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.17",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.60.30",
        "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.1",
        "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.4",
        "@types/styled-components": "^4.4.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.26.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.26.0",
        "apk-parser": "^0.1.7",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "husky": "^4.2.3",
        "jest": "^26.4.2",
        "js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
        "jshint": "^2.11.0-rc1",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.4",
        "node-apk-parser": "^0.2.3",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5",
        "prettier-eslint": "^9.0.1",
        "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-perf-middleware": "1.2.2",
        "simple-git": "^2.44.0",
        "ts-jest": "^26.3.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.2.0",
        "typescript": "^4.4.4"
    },
```

My current babel.conig.js

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);

    const presets = ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'];
    const plugins = [
        ['dynamic-import-node'],
        [
            'module-resolver',
            {
                root: ['./src'],
                extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.ios.js', '.android.js'],
                alias: {
                    // when changed here also change in tsconfig.json
                    actions: './src/actions',
                    components: './src/components',
                    constants: './src/constants',
                    images: './src/images',
                    lib: './src/lib',
                    reducers: './src/reducers',
                    sagas: './src/sagas',
                    screens: './src/screens',
                    utils: './src/utils',
                    types: './src/types',
                },
            },
        ],
    ];

    return {
        presets,
        plugins,
    };
};
```

Comment: Same here,. you got any clue

Comment: Nothing. Looks like an issue w/ the yarn.lock file getting re-created and changed the babel dependencies got changed from the prior yarn.lock/package.lock file.  You may be able to lock down your lock files prior.

Comment: able to resolve by removing one unwanted npm install @Robel

Comment: was it a banel dep? https://stackoverflow.com/users/948209/arjun-t-raj

Comment: in my case ya , due to babel core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we decided to take the big plunge. upgrade the project from rn 61.5 to 67! it only took 2 days ;) wish we would have started there...